# Android Async Task not executing when creating New object

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My app executes an asynctask when a checkbox is clicked. I cant get it to Log a message more than once. It does on the first click but not again. After looking around at other questions I determined I had to build a custom class and of course call new MyAysncTask (which I was already doing) but it still is not working.

Here is the code that executes when a checkbox is clicked.

```
cbJoining.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        new MyAsyncTask(EventID, cbJoining.isChecked(), URL_Race, sDates, sState ).execute();
    }
});
```

Here is the custom class

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{  

    public String EventID;
    public boolean bJoin;
    public String URL_Race;
    public String sDates;
    public String sState;

    public MyAsyncTask( String myEventID, boolean mybJoin, String myURL_Race, String mysDates, String mysState){
        super();
        EventID = myEventID;
        bJoin = mybJoin;
        URL_Race = myURL_Race;
        sDates = mysDates;
        sState = mysState;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() { 
    };

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

        //Looper.prepare();

        API oAPI = new API();
        oAPI.Join(mPrefs, EventID, bJoin, URL_Race, sDates, sState);

        Log.d("ASYNCTASK", URL_Race);

        //Looper.loop();

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.d("ASYNCTASK", "Finished");
    };
}
```

Here is the exception:
07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:197)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:111)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at android.app.Activity.(Activity.java:759)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at com.chartermatrixllc.motocrossmatrix.API$FB.(API.java:88)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at com.chartermatrixllc.motocrossmatrix.API.Join(API.java:125)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at com.chartermatrixllc.motocrossmatrix.Race$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(Race.java:207)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at com.chartermatrixllc.motocrossmatrix.Race$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(Race.java:1)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)

07-16 12:45:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28309):    ... 4 more

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem but from this code I don't see any need for the `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()`. If you do need it then you should be calling `Looper.quit()` somewhere

Answer (score 2):

You are probably working on Android 4+, from that version `AsyncTask` has only one thread and you blocked it with

```
    Looper.prepare();

    Log.d("ASYNCTASK", "Clicked");

    Looper.loop();
```

So now you have several options:

1) use method `AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor` and provide you own executor with some number of threads, for example `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`

2) stop blocking `AsyncTask` thread

Comment: Assuming I want to do more instead of Log, say download some JSON, how can I stop blocking the thread? When I remove Looper.prepare and Looper.loop() I get an exception when doing a long task like downloading data, telling me I must include looper.prepare()

Comment: If you just want to do a long running task you don't need to invoke
`Looper.prepare(); Looper.loop();`. Just write the code for this task and that's all.

Comment: I thought that but without it I get this exception when first calling it:   
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() I am simply trying to POST some data to the server more than once

Comment: Why do you need to create a Handler inside AsyncTask?

Comment: I am unsure why it is even throwing that error. I am not creating a handler

Comment: Can you show the complete code of AsyncTask which throws error?

Comment: I updated it to show exactly what im running, which is just a call to my API object that POSTs JSON to the server and gets a response.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33576/discussion-between-user1873880-and-masteroleary)

Answer (score 0):

A `Looper` shall not be attached to the worker thread in an `AsyncTask` for multiple reasons, where the main two are:

1. If `Looper.loop()` is called, the worker thread is occupied with handling and waiting for incoming messages, i.e. it blocks the thread so that no other tasks can be executed. This is always a bad thing, but it is an application performance killer after API level 11, where `AsyncTask.execute()` processes tasks sequentially, making consecutive tasks wait for the blocking task to finish.
2. Even if only `Looper.prepare()` is called, the worker thread is associated with a message queue. This can only be done once, so the second time a task is executed and `Looper.prepare()` is called again, a `RuntimeException` is thrown. Consequently, the `AsyncTask` can only be executed once.

From the code example it is not clear why you need a `Looper` on the worker thread, but if it is a requirement, you should not use an `AsyncTask` but instead a `HandlerThread`. The `HandlerThread` is a background thread with a `Looper`. The drawback is that you will have to handle the message passing between the UI thread and the background thread yourself.

Comment: I added Looper.loop() because when I ran the app without it I got an exception stating **Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()**

I am simply trying to POST some data to the server more than once.

Comment: Where is the `Handler` created? In your code or the platform/library code?

Comment: I apologize, that handler line should not be in there. I originally started from code in another app that works, but I think changes in the new API have since broken it. I spent a lot of time trying multiple solutions I found online with no success and the Handler line is left over from one of those tests. Now I am looking into HandlerThread as you suggested. I'm obviously clueless and may be getting confused from so many examples across various API levels.

Comment: From the stacktrace you added it is the motocrossmatrix-library that creates the `Handler` and that is why it is required that the background thread has a `Looper`. This will be solved by the `HandlerThread`, which is unchanged across API-levels.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
        new MyAsyncTask(EventID, cbJoining.isChecked(), URL_Race, sDates, sState ).execute();
            }
        });
```

for any other AsyncTask related doubt u can refer,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36078608/2249287