# understanding parallel Async Task in android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, threadpool

In my application I am using Async tasks in many places, recently I am facing problem where doInBackground of the below Async task is not getting called, this is happening when I execute the below Async task for the 3rd time (other Async tasks are also running).

```
protected class StatusTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final BluetoothDevice device;

    public StatusTask(BluetoothDevice device) {
        this.device = device;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        while (true) {
            if (someCondition) {
                Log.D(TAG,"hi hello")
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        tTask=null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        System.out.println("onCancelled " + this.isCancelled());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(Void aVoid) {
        super.onCancelled(aVoid);
        System.out.println("onCancelled result " + this.isCancelled());
    }
}
```

i am executing above task as,

```
 StatusTask  tTask = new StatusTask(device);   
 tTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

I am running on Android version 4.4.3.

1. How do I find out how many Sync tasks are running currently in my app? Bcz I guess CORE_POOL_SIZE count might be causing the problem.
2. Or if deadlock or any other situation is happened and blocking new Async task to get executed, is there a way in android studio to identity and kill the other Async tasks which may not be useful?
3. If I use CustomThreadPoolExecutor as disconnectTask.executeOnExecutor(mCustomThreadPoolExecutor); with more CorePoolSize its working fine but doInBackground() of next Async task which is using AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR is not getting called.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html and http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi thanku  Stallion and royB for replay....i found what was causing the problem...

criteria for multiple AsynC task is as below,

**Before Donut (Till 1.6 Version)**

```
There was no concept of Multiple AsyncTask.
```

**After Donut and till Honeycomb (1.6 – 3.0)**

```
Here it uses multiple AsyncTask in parallel by default and you cannot customize it.
```

**After Honeycomb and till Jelly Bean (Version 3.0 – 4.3.1)**

```
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 5;
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 128;
private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10);
```

**From KitKat (4.4 Above):**

```
private static final int CPU_COUNT = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT + 1;
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT * 2 + 1;
private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(128);
```

As i am running on Android version: 4.4.3 ,i used Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();  to print CPU_COUNT in my logs it showed 2 so 2+1=3 is the CORE_POOL_SIZE for my device,
as i can see from studio debugger console below,

[image]

simultaneously only 3 threads can run in my device and as those threads were already occupied(running).. as i was using while loop in doInbackground() method, those Async Task was never getting finished so new AsyncTask will go to queue and was not getting the Thread to execute.
now i have made sure that Async Task are properly terminated as soon as its work is over. and after my fix u can see below that Async Tasks(Threads) are available(in wait state) to take up the new Task...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you are running `AsyncTask` multiple times, they all run in a Queue on the same thread, Thus until 1 task didn't finish, the next will NOT start.

Because you never finish the Task...the next task will not start

Have a look at [AsyncTask video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtlRNNhane0)