# Notification blocks UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-notifications, android-intentservice

My app has an option to download a file. It works in this way:
Activity -> IntentService -> AsyncTask (here the file is downloading). Additionally, I use a notification to show progress in percents, and here is my problem: everything works well e.g. on Android 2.3, but on Android 4.2 or 5.0, the UI is blocked.

Earlier I had a bug in my code (I updated the progress bar in a loop every time), and now when I update it only when oldProgress != actualProgress, it works well (100+ operations instead of 2000+). But why does it work well on Android 2.3 even with 2000+ operations?

Here is my notification class:

```
public class NotificationProgressHelper {
private static final int DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

private Context mContext;
private Notification mNotification;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private PendingIntent mContentIntent;
private CharSequence mContentTitle;

public NotificationProgressHelper(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

public void createNotification() {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int icon = R.drawable.download_icon;
    CharSequence contentName = mContext.getString(R.string.notification_content_name);
    mNotification = new Notification(icon, contentName, System.currentTimeMillis());

    mContentTitle = mContext.getString(R.string.notification_title);
    CharSequence contentText = mContext.getString(R.string.notification_percent_completed, 0);

    //pending intent left blank till the whole apk file will be downloaded
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
    mContentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(mContext, mContentTitle, contentText, mContentIntent);
    mNotification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    mNotificationManager.notify(DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS_NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
}

public void progressUpdate(int percentageComplete) {
    CharSequence contentText = mContext.getString(R.string.notification_percent_completed, percentageComplete);
    mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(mContext, mContentTitle, contentText, mContentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS_NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
}

public void completed() {
    mNotificationManager.cancel(DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS_NOTIFICATION_ID);
}

public void removeDownloadSuccessNotification() {
    mNotificationManager.cancel(ApplicationConstants.NotificationID.APP_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_ID);
}
```

The downloadFile method is called in doInBackground(), of course.

I know this code is old and now I should use the builder but I tried and it does not concern the problem.

Am I doing something wrong? Why does the version with all operations work well on Android 2.3? I think it works on the main thread but why?

Comment: please paste your AsyncTask code.

Answer (score 0):

After Donut and till Honeycomb (1.6 – 3.0) till Version 3.0
it uses multiple AsyncTask in parallel by default so may be that is the reason why its working fine.. 
detailed explanation regarding the same can be reffered in, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36078608/2249287

Comment: So is any possible to run notifications in separate thread in my case?